# How do I render a video hosted by Vimeo.com?

Tags: android, listview

This is my first Android project after a while so please bear with me or direct me to the right link if this question has already been answered.

I am building an android app that plays videos hosted by Vimeo.com My client has given me access to their account.

I am using VideoView in the android studio to render the video. 
An example of a video I am trying to play is:
"https://vimeo.com/108326279"
When I run the app it runs the error "can't play this video".

I am almost certain, it has to do with Vimeo server because when I try to play different links. This link, for instance, runs fine:
"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"

Can you guys help me figure out where I am having the issue?

Kind Regards

Comment: you can not direct play video from vimeo server, they have a restriction to play video without that own player for security. So you need to go vimeo developer page and choose option to which way you want to play vimeo video in your app.

developer Link : https://developer.vimeo.com/

Comment: also, use the webview for the load the video.

Answer (score 0):

use webview to play video`

```
private void openWebView(String mVideoUrl) {




    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(Constant.BASE_URL_VIDEO + mVideoUrl);

    Log.e("get Video Id==", "" + Constant.BASE_URL_VIDEO + mVideoUrl);

}
```